# Java MVC and Rest Server and JavaScript Heavy Client

Tags: java, javascript, model-view-controller, jsp, rest

I am in the process of beginning development of a web-based user interface and am looking for some expert advice on the right direction for my project.

Since our server-side is to be developed using Java, I am planning to use scriptless-JSP and an MVC framework called FrontMan. FrontMan is a lightweight Java-based MVC framework similar to Struts. I have played around with it and like it. The plan is to use scriptless-JSP assisted by JSTL and JSP tag files. I worked out some prototypes using these technologies and I liked what I had.

Now I am in the process of planning out the client-side stuff. My plan is to use JavaScript, jQuery, jQuery UI to build the front end. During my investigation I came across a very nifty JavaScript MVC framework named JavaScriptMVC. I have to say I really like it. It is not just a client-side MVC framework, but also includes tools for testing, documenting and deploying.

The more I engage in figuring out the client-side plan, I realize that I think this is going to be more of a JavaScript (client-side) app. I am leaning towards doing as much of the work in JavaScript rather than on the backend via Java. The backend will exist mostly for communicating with the database and responding to requests from the client (frontend) for manipulating or retrieving data.

I am rather new to RESTful web services, but in the little I have read about them, I think this might be a good direction to take this project.

I am wondering how I can employ both an MVC framework and REST framework together? Do they make sense together?

I am using Jetty as my web server, so I think that lends itself to using Restlets...?

Anyway, I am not sure how much sense I am making in this post, so I will stop it there for now.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous poster mentioned, it makes perfect sence. MVC let's you separate concerns such that you can keep your application logic separate from your presentational logic.

Your REST controller serves the request you need, populates the model, and exposes it in a REST like manner, typically by returning an xml view to the user. This can be aided by a number of libraries such as xstream, jaxb, castor, xmlbeans, which all provides routines to marshall an object into xml.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing a REST API on the server-side will be a perfect fit for your JS front-end. Your resources will have to expose JSON representations. You will even be able to reuse this web API from other clients such as mobile phones.

As the lead for the [Restlet Framework](http://www.restlet.org), I can only recommend it for this purpose. Integration with Jetty is very stable :)

Cheers,
Jerome

Answer (score 0):

A quite extensive discussion on this can also be found here:
[Separate REST JSON API server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941249/separate-rest-json-api-server-and-)

For me it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It makes sense as Johan Sjöberg said! You can use Spring MVC for example. I like it a lot and think it is very simple and easy to learn. You have an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/).

By the away, for the frontend maybe you would like to check this [presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/addyosmani/automating-front-end-workflow).