# Server Side Rendering/Templating

Tags: mysql, rest, backbone.js, server-side

We are going to create some applications that will access the same api. We decided that the backed part will be developed in `node.js` and the database will be MySQL and maybe some parts `mongoDB`.

I have problem deciding about the front end of the web application that will be a website. Taking a look on this question: [Separate REST JSON API server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941249/separate-rest-json-api-server-and-client) we decided that fits better to us server side templating/rendering.

Do you think that using a PHP framework (like symfony, laravel etc) only for templating is good solution, or is it stupid to use a complete framework that offers a lot of features that we are not going to use only for templating? I was thinking to use twig that is only a template engine and try to fit backbone on it just to structure better the ajax calls to the `RESTful` API.

Do you have something different to suggest for server side rendering?

I have no experience at all, thats why i am writing to prevent taking bad decisions.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of awesome templating options for Node.JS! Here's a small list of some that I've used:

- [hogan](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) (by twitter, feels like mustache)
- [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) (by tjholowaychuk, same code-machine behind express and a bunch of other awesome node projects)
- [ginger](https://github.com/deoxxa/node-ginger) (by yours truly!)
- [swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) (my personal favourite right now)
- [ejs](http://embeddedjs.com/) (simple javascript-in-html thing, feels like php)

I like swig right now. It's basically what I wanted to build when I was working on ginger. It looks and feels a lot like django's templating system, which many popular template languages (twig, for example) have been inspired by.

Comment: I would like to specify that i don't want to be together in node.js. I just want to develop a different client for the api.

Comment: In that case, it might be a good idea to remove the node.js tag from this question.