# Rails consuming internal REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

[Separate REST JSON API server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941249/separate-rest-json-api-server-and-client)

I am looking for advice on how to consume my own API (like Twitter is said to) for an app that I plan on making.

I would like to have a REST API that I can then use for an web app, Android app and some analytics/dashboard apps.

Rails has a respond_with option, and I have seen some apps that have an html and json option, but I think that is a less than stellar way of doing things and json is data and html is for presentation, and you are not making use of your json API essentially

It seems stupid but how exactly would I use my REST api from Rails if I want to do a server side html solution? Using something like HTTParty seems like a lot of work, is there a way to access the API more directly (in ASP MVC for example you can instantiate a controller class and then call its methods for example.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HTTParty and create client model classes that resemble a rails models by including ActiveModel modules.

activeresource gem was used in previous rails versions, but they deprecated it in favor of HTTParty+ActiveModel like solutions.

#### Update

I have crafted this example (from memory) with the basic ideas, is not a full implementation but I think you will get the idea.

```
class Post
  # Attributes handling
  include Virtus

  # ActiveModel
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  # HTTParty
  include HTTParty

  # Virtus attributes
  attribute :id, Integer
  attribute :title, String
  attribute :content, Text # not sure about this one, read virtus doc

  # Validations
  validates :title, presence: true

  def save
    return false unless valid?

    if persisted?
      self.class.put("/posts/#{id}", attributes)
    else
      self.class.post("/posts", attributes)
    end
  end

  # This is needed for form_for
  def persisted?
    # If we have an id we assume this model is saved
    id.present?
  end

  def decorate
    @decorator ||= PostDecorator.decorate(self)
  end
end
```

gems needed:

- httparty
- activemodel (present in rails)
- virtus
- draper

Comment: So you would create HTTP requests and 'unpack' the data received into what could be described as 'view models'?

Comment: View models? Like backbone models? Not what I said, but that's another option (option #2 of the linked question)

I mean ActiveRecord like models, that you can use seamlessly in your views, for example `link_to 'name', @model` or `form_for(@model)`

Comment: Sorry 'view model' is vague, I meant just objects that basically support building up the user interface like the Draper project https://github.com/drapergem/draper, but yes I am also interested in a Backbone solution or a hybrid server side html and Backbone solution.

Comment: Do you know of any links to any OSS projects that use the approach as per your answer for reference

Comment: Yes, you can do it, in fact I use a similar solution to consume an external api. I'll try to craft an example for you.