# Django Rest Framework and Angular App on same AWS Instance

Tags: django, angularjs, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Django Rest Framework for API service and Angular to use those APIs. How do I run Angular alongside Django Rest Framework on the EC2 instance using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

For example, Django Rest Framework serves up the API through `http://test.com/api/v1/` and Angular makes HTTP requests to those API endpoints client-side.

What are the steps required to run Django Rest Framework API with an angular client side application on the same machine?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for a customized container that runs both a Python web app and an Angular app. The angular app accesses the django REST API on "localhost". I would recommend looking into creating a custom Docker container that lets you have this custom configuration.

You can read more on support of Docker containers on Elastic Beanstalk [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you more details on setting up the Docker container to the configuration we need? I'm researching it now, but I was wondering if you had any experience with it.

Comment: A simple walkthrough of setting up a docker application on Elastic Beanstalk. http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-docker/
You can search for docker images that satisfy your usecase here: https://registry.hub.docker.com/
You can also create a new Docker image for your custom needs and then use it. For example you can find a django image and then install stuff needed for angular on top of it in your dockerfile.

Comment: Very cool, thanks a lot man! Upvoted your answer, I'll look into it. I'll wait before accepting it as the answer to see if anyone else have any other suggestions, but I appreciate your input! :)

Comment: I'm working on the same, I'm using nginx container & python:3 container - I will post my shell scripts to rebuild/restart containers on code updates when they are done.

Comment: @Vincent did you get a chance to get it done? Looking forward to seeing it!

Comment: AWS Elastic Beanstalk only supports a single docker container, i have 2.. I haven't figured out yet if I can deploy 2 containers and easily link them within AWS.. I'm thinking I'm better off with a simple VPS that can run docker. I'm supposed to provide the answer to my team by this Saturday... I wonder if there are complete guides on setting up a micro services app on EB

Answer (score 1):

While there may be simpler solutions out there I have been able to configure AngularJS + Django REST Framework to run on the same AWS instance. It's the accepted answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/22852451/1759504

There I go into detail on exactly what I had to do to make it so my static AngularJS content runs from `http://test.com/#/` while my APIs are at `http://test.com/api/v1/`