# oAuth2 authentication on a JavaScript app

Tags: javascript, security, oauth

I'm planning to refactor a legacy Rails 2 app by splitting the logic into a RESTful API, and the view into a separate Javascript client. The API itself will be protected by oAuth2. This is basically the second option explained on this question:

[Separate REST JSON API server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941249/separate-rest-json-api-server-and-client)

There's a lot of questions out there concerning the security of using oAuth with a JS app, the main concern seems to be that storing the access token on the client is a bad idea since it acts as a password and someone that has physical access to the computer can hijack the user's identity. A possible solution I've read is to expire the access token every 1h or so and use the refresh token stored on Yahoo's YQL to request a new token when necessary. This doesn't looks to me like a good solution since at the end you'll need again a token to access the YQL service.

But at the end, aren't we facing the same problem as when using persistent sessions? I mean, AFAIK, the common method to keep the session alive across browser opening/closing (when you tick "remember me") is to generate a token associated to a user and store it both on the DB and on a long-living cookie. So again, anyone with access to this cookie has the "key" to your session. AFAIK this is the method all the "big guys" use.

I am right? And if I am, aren't we worrying too much about something that we cannot control at all? Of course I'm talking about those applications where an intrusion is not too harmful for the user like social networks, blogs, forums, etc.