# Can we use Rails default controller for Mobile API request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have Rails application, I want the CRUD functionality in my android mobile.

Rails provides default respond_to actions (html, json, xml..etc) in all controllers. I have been developing mobile application for android. I want to do CRUD operation in my mobile Rails application. 
Can we use this default respond_to for API calls?

If we do separate namespace for API, same method / code written in default all controllers, have to write again for API all controllers also.

I can't able to apply RAILS **DRY** concept here!.

What are the best ways to do API functionality in Rails without repeating controller code or model code?

Comment: Can't you write the code at one place only, and then use `format.html` for browser request, and `format.json` for API calls?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as stated a above. But I would not suggest it as seems to be the [consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941249/separate-rest-json-api-server-and-client). I would go head and create a separate base controller where you could do things like disable disable csrf checking. Also you would probably have a lot of token code being used in browser clients where you only need it in the api calls. [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) is a great gem build for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use default `respond_to` method for api calls.

```
respond_to do |format|

  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }

end
```

Another way is to specify default format in `routes.rb`

```
resources :clients, defaults: {format: :json}
```

These are DRY ways to make an API. To serialized `json` properly you can use [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) or [jBuilder Gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

Rails has a special [gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) `rails-api` specifically for creating apis. Consider using that instead of rails